# putting a window within a window

Tags: c, winapi, window, parent-child

i am now assigned to make a graph/Cartesian plane making program, and i was asked to do it in C, or more precisely, in Win32, i have a little problem though, i wanted to put a popup window inside my window as a  makeshift Graphing field, the problem is when i create the window, the supposed to be "Graphing field" appears outside the main/parent window and it seems to use the whole screen as the reference to it's location, rather than the assigned parent/main window:

```
HWND DrawGrap(HWND hwnd)
{
LPSTR nme = "graph";
WNDCLASSEX c;
c.style = CS_VREDRAW|CS_HREDRAW;
c.lpfnWndProc = MathProc;
c.cbClsExtra = 0;
c.cbWndExtra = 0;
c.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
c.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);
c.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);
c.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
c.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
c.lpszMenuName = NULL;
c.lpszClassName = nme;
c.cbSize = sizeof(c);

RegisterClassEx(&c);

return CreateWindowEx(0,nme,"",WS_VISIBLE|WS_POPUP|WS_CHILD,
                      10, 10,
                      460,200,hwnd,NULL,GetModuleHandle(NULL),0);

 }
 void InitializeUI(HWND hwnd)
{       
    //Graph
    DrawGrap(hwnd);
    //GroupBoxes for coordinate inputs
    P1BOX = CreateWindowEx(0,"BUTTON","Point 1",
                        WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_GROUPBOX,
                        10,230,225,120,hwnd,(HMENU)111,
                        GetModuleHandle(NULL),0);                       
    P2BOX = CreateWindowEx(0,"BUTTON","Point 2",
                        WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_GROUPBOX,
                        250,230,225,120,hwnd,(HMENU)112,
                        GetModuleHandle(NULL),0);

    //Coordinate Labels:
    CreateLabel("X :",P1BOX,30);
    CreateLabel("Y :",P1BOX,80);
    CreateLabel("X :",P2BOX,30);
    CreateLabel("Y :",P2BOX,80);                
    //Input boxes
    hP1X = CreateBox(P1BOX,40,30,P1X);
    hP1Y = CreateBox(P1BOX,40,80,P1X);
    hP2X = CreateBox(P2BOX,40,30,P1X);
    hP2Y = CreateBox(P2BOX,40,80,P1X);

    //buttons
    CreateButton("Gen. Equation",125,360,hwnd,GENEQBTN);
    CreateButton("Point-Slope",255,360,hwnd,PSLOPEBTN);
    CreateButton("Slope-intercept",125,395,hwnd,SINTERCEPTBTN);
    CreateButton("Intercept",255,395,hwnd,INTERCEPTBTN);
    CreateButton("Slope",195,430,hwnd,SLOPEBTN);
 }
```

however when i replace the NULL in the:

```
return CreateWindowEx(0,nme,"",WS_VISIBLE|WS_POPUP|WS_CHILD,
                      10, 10,
                      460,200,hwnd,NULL,GetModuleHandle(NULL),0);
```

with:

```
return CreateWindowEx(0,nme,"",WS_VISIBLE|WS_POPUP|WS_CHILD,
                      10, 10,
                      460,200,hwnd,(HMENU)443,GetModuleHandle(NULL),0);
```

the "Graphing-field" seems to diappear. how do i fix this

Comment: Are you sure you want a pop-up rather than just a child window?

Comment: i just wanted to get the illusion of it being a Picture box, without the frames, so i thought WS_POPUP would help me do that.

Comment: I think you'd be better with `WS_CHILD` and maybe `WS_BORDER` if you want a thin line around it. In any case you can't use `WS_POPUP` and `WS_CHILD` together as you have in your code - [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that popup windows do not respect their parent's offset.

Use [ClientToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to convert coordinates inside the parent window into screen coordinates and then create the popup window with the converted coordinates.